# Power BI limit of 1000 values reached

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm using Power BI version 2.117.984. I loaded an Excel sheet containing the working hours, but I noticed that not the whole data is loaded, as a consequence, I have less working hours in Power BI than in the Excel sheet.

I verified the whole column in Power BI, and there is all the data, but when I try to write some "section code" corresponding to the hours in the filter, it doesn't work.

Why doesn't Power BI load the whole Excel sheet?

Comment: How do you know there are only 1,000 rows? I just created a sheet with 10,000 rows; loaded it into Power BI, and all 10,000 rows were there. Please provide more details, including the code used to load the sheet as well as your method of determining the number of rows in Power BI.